# Adding GeoTag image details

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geotag, exif

I'm using QGIS 3.16 and I need to add some EXIF details to images, such as elevation or time. I am using the following code in Python console to add location to images, reading params from a table and it works fine:

```
from qgis.analysis import *
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    fotoPath = feature["foto"]
    lon = feature["longitue"]
    lat = feature["latitude"]
    ele = feature["elevation"]
    point = QgsPointXY(float(lon), float(lat))
    QgsExifTools.geoTagImage(fotoPath, point)
```

but I can't figure out how to add the elevation tag.

Comment: Have a look here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/analysis/QgsExifTools.html#qgis.analysis.QgsExifTools.geoTagImage. This can be done via an additional `details` argument to the `geoTagImage` function.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `GeoTagDetails` class defined in `QgsExifTools` class, as below:

```
...

details = QgsExifTools().GeoTagDetails()
details.elevation = float(ele)

QgsExifTools().geoTagImage(fotoPath, point, details)
```

[image]